# Reverse proxy using hop and RDP

Tags: windows, ssh, remote-desktop, putty, tunnel

I am trying to connect from Vista to XP using RDP via  reverse proxy using putty and  an intermidiate host.  There are myriad articles on the internet how to do it using vnc, ssh servers, winsshd, etc, but I can't find anything that helps me in this specific case.

What I have:

1. Windows XP host behind the firewall - 'destination'
2. linux host running ssh on the internet - 'intermediate'
3. windows host behind the firewall - 'source'

All I want to do is open reverse tunnel from destination to intermidiate and use this tunnel  for connecting back from the source.   That should be simple to setup, however I just cannot make it.

This is what I do:

- On 'destination', open putty session, create tunnel to 'intermediate' using following settings:
  source port 3389, destination is 'source:33389', direction is local
- On 'source', open putty session, create tunnel to 'intermediate'using following settings:
  source port 33389, destination is 'destination:33389', direction is local
- Finally, on source, open termnal services client and connect it to localhost:33389.Unfortunately it seems like packets do go somewhere but eventually client times out.

Am I totally misunderstanding the concept?
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should be close, but here is the setup you should have:

- On *destination*, open PuTTY session and create a tunnel to *intermediate* using the following settings

  - Source port: 33898
  - Destination: **localhost:3389**
  - **Remote**

**Explanation:**
Since the connection is originating from *source*, and you want to listen on a port on   *intermediate* to be forwarded to *source*, the tunnel must be **remote**.  So a socket will be opened on port 33389 on *intermediate* which will be output on the local machine(*destination*) to `localhost:3389`, where the RDP server is listening.

Technically that is all you should need.  As long as your *source* computer can see *intermediate* and *intermediate* will accept connections from the internet on port 33389, you should be able to point your RDP client to *intermediate:33389* and be done with it.

**Update:** In order to have just the single tunnel you do need to select the *Remote ports do the same* checkbox, and as the [PuTTY manual](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-port-forwarding) states, this feature may be disabled on the server.

However, if you do want to tunnel your connection from *source* to *intermediate* as well, here is the second part of the conifg:

- On *source*, open a PuTTY session and create a tunnel to *intermediate* using the following settings:

  - Source port: 3389
  - Destination: **localhost:33389**
  - Local
  - Point the RDP client on *source* to `localhost` and it should connect.

Comment: Thanksa lot!
Some clarifications:
Did you mean Source port 33389?
"will accept connections from the internet on port 3389" - I need to intermediate on arbitrary host , hence 33389.

Comment: Thank you, I think I grasp the concept now.
There is also setting in Putty  "Local ports accept connections from other hosts" -should not it be enabled?

Comment: I think I fixed any discrepancies in the port numbers.  And see my updated for the second question.